# Executar query sem foreach

Tags: php

Como faço pra executar esse codigo sem foreach,ele esta completamente vazio e so esta servindo pra dar valor aos atributos, logo ele nao esta listando nada, e eu queria deixar o codigo mais limpo e clean, entao queria saber como faço para executar a linha `$con->query($sql, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row`" sem precisar do `foreach`.

```
$con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=estagio;charset=utf8", "root", "");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE id_cliente = '$_SESSION[id]'";
foreach($con->query($sql, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row){
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seria assim:

```
$var = $con->query($sql, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($var);
```

Mas se tiver mais de 1 registro, só irá trazer o último.

A repetição serve para ler linha por linha, e ir armazenando na variável que posteriormente será usada. Então se não fizer dessa forma, ele ficará sobrepondo sua variável (neste caso `$var`).